# How to make a stamp inside the rectangle?

Tags: draftwatermark

I want to a stamp like the red box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multido,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem,anyfontsize}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\begin{document}
\centering
\multido{}{12}
{
\begin{minipage}{0.43\textwidth}
\selectlanguage{english} Dabbas, Zahdi, Neghal \selectlanguage{bengali} ও\selectlanguage{english} Moriom \selectlanguage{bengali}খেজুর, শুকনা খেজুর, বরই, কালোজিরা, সরিষা ও  লিচু ফুলের মধু, কালোজিরা ও তিলের তেল, কাঠবাদাম, কিসমিস, কালোজিরা পাওয়া যায়\\\selectlanguage{english}01515-611989(Al-Helal, CSE)\\
\selectlanguage{bengali}রুম \selectlanguage{english}- 1406, \selectlanguage{english}Ex-1, \selectlanguage{bengali}শহীদুল্লাহ হল\\
\selectlanguage{english}\includegraphics[height=\fontcharht\font`\B]{Image/facebook-icon.png} Honey\&Date\\ website: https://al2helal.github.io/business.html\\\selectlanguage{bengali} [** ৫০০ টাকার জিনিস কিনলে ফ্রি হল ডেলিভারি **]
\end{minipage}\vspace{0.5cm}
}
\end{document}
```

I want this type of stamp in the document each minipage.
[image]

Comment: You should be more specific. Do you also want it placed in the holes within the text? Or just a stamp in general? Is there only text in the block?

Comment: `picin` package helps.

Comment: @Werner yes, only text.

Comment: @alhelal: Should the stamp be placed in such a way that the text wraps around it? Will the text always remain the same?

Comment: @Werner you put the text in any orientation inside the box, but the text may be changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a very general answer, in the sense that you may have to change the box/stamp dimensions with your text... but it should work if there's nothing better at hand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multido, tikz}

\begin{document}
\centering
\multido{}{8}
{
  \begin{minipage}{0.43\textwidth}\sffamily
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw[green!50!black, 
          ultra thick, 
          rotate = 30, 
          rounded corners] (0,-2) rectangle (3.8,-3.5);
    \node[green!50!black, 
          rotate = 30] at (3,-1.4) {\Huge\bfseries Received};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %
  \quad Well, this paragraph gives the list of
  several items that can be considered to
  be ingredients of a special dish for the
  emperor, badshah or nawab of Bengal.
  Once he gets to collect these items his
  cook can cook them to a savoury dish
  which every member of the royal family
  can taste and relish over this Winter.
  %
  \end{minipage}\hspace{0.5cm}\vspace{0.5cm}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: new line not work at `\Huge\bfseries Received}` I try `\Huge\bfseries Received\\OK}`. To do this should I use separate node.

Comment: @alhelal Yes. `\node [...] at (2.8,-1.2) {\Huge\bfseries Received};` followed by a node below: `\node [...] at (3,-1.9) {\Huge\bfseries OK};` should do.

Comment: Is there a reason to separate the box from the text? I find it simpler to use this one-liner: `\node[rectangle,draw,rounded corners,ultra thick,green!50!black,rotate=30] at (3, -1.4) {\Huge\bfseries Received};`